# postgresql - find Discontinuous id and get read_time

Tags: postgresql, lag, postgresql-9.4, row-number, lead

I have a table like this, and there are three cases,

```
## case a
| rec_no |      read_time      | id
+--------+---------------------+----
|  45139 | 2023-02-07 17:00:00 | a
|  45140 | 2023-02-07 17:15:00 | a
|  45141 | 2023-02-07 17:30:00 | a
|  45142 | 2023-02-07 18:15:00 | a
|  45143 | 2023-02-07 18:30:00 | a
|  45144 | 2023-02-07 18:45:00 | a
```

```
## case b
| rec_no |      read_time      | id
+--------+---------------------+----
|  21735 | 2023-02-01 19:15:00 | b
|  21736 | 2023-02-01 19:30:00 | b
|  21742 | 2023-02-01 21:00:00 | b
|  21743 | 2023-02-01 21:15:00 | b
|  21744 | 2023-02-01 21:30:00 | b
|  21745 | 2023-02-01 21:45:00 | b
```

```
## case c
| rec_no |      read_time      | id
+--------+---------------------+----
|  12345 | 2023-02-02 12:15:00 | c
|  12346 | 2023-02-02 12:30:00 | c
|  12347 | 2023-02-02 12:45:00 | c
|  12348 | 2023-02-02 13:15:00 | c
|  12352 | 2023-02-02 14:00:00 | c
|  12353 | 2023-02-02 14:15:00 | c
```

*I'd like to find out the missing readtime field when the rec is not continuous.*

- *read_time is '15 min' interval*
- in different 'id', rec_no are independent

I'd like something like this,

```
## case a
## nothing because rec_no is continous
|      read_time      | id
+---------------------+----
```

```
## case b
## get six rows
|      read_time      | id
+--------+-----------------
| 2023-02-01 19:45:00 | b
| 2023-02-01 20:00:00 | b
| 2023-02-01 20:15:00 | b
| 2023-02-01 20:30:00 | b
| 2023-02-01 20:45:00 | b
| 2023-02-01 21:00:00 | b
```

```
## case c
## get two rows (13:00:00 is missing but rec_no is continous)
|      read_time      | id
+--------+-----------------
| 2023-02-02 13:30:00 | c
| 2023-02-02 13:45:00 | c
```

Is there a way to do this ? The output format is not too important as long as I can get the result correctly.

Comment: with the window function LAG you can check the last row against the actual row, and so find out if rows are missing, and with LED the next row

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[step-by-step demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XYtzCQ5T)

```
SELECT
    rec_no,
    id,
    gs
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        lead(rec_no) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rec_no) - rec_no > 1 AS is_gap,  -- 1
        lead(read_time) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rec_no) as next_read_time
    FROM mytable
)s, generate_series(                                                                 -- 3
      read_time + interval '15 minutes',                                             -- 4
      next_read_time - interval '15 minutes', 
      interval '15 minutes'
  ) as gs
WHERE is_gap                                                                         -- 2
```

1. Use [`lead()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to move the next `rec_no` value and the next `read_time` value to the current row. With this you can check if the difference between the current and next `rec_no` values are greater than `1`.
2. Filter all records with greater differences
3. Generate a time series with 15 minutes interval
4. Because the series includes start and end, you need a start at the next 15 minutes points (+ interval) and end one "slot" before the next recorded value (- interval).

Comment: Thank you so much! This works well! The only one problem is "when rec_no turn to zero is_gap will be NULL". I'd like to know if it's possible that "is_gap = f when rec_no turn to zero"?

Comment: `COALESCE(<nullable_expression_here>, false)` should do it.